# Job inside spark application is complete but I still see the status as running, why?

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a spark application that completed all its jobs but still the status of this job yarn cluster portal is RUNNING (for more than 30 mins). Please let me know why it is happening.

**Spark UI showing my jobs are completed**

[image: Spark UI showing my jobs are completed]

**Spark application status is still running**

[image: Spark application status is still running]

Comment: did you find the solution?? I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Spark 2.4.8 running on K8S, I didn’t understand why, but I solved it by stopping the context manually

```
spark.sparkContext.stop()
```